# Decorations on drawbridge

Tags: design, castle

At about 0:28 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99jXY7oCmz4), it depicts a descending drawbridge with some metal decorations. Are there any decorated tiles that come close to this? Is there some other way I could achieve a similar looking effect?

Comment: I've certainly seen a lot of 1x4 tiles with printed decoration of a slightly worn-out wood plank, but none that have ever had 'metal' on them.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Yeah, here's one: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431pb243&name=Tile%201%20x%204%20with%20Wood%20Grain%20and%204%20Nails%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=88 As you can see there are nails on it which count as metal, but almost all wood planks have nails so it doesn't really count.

Answer (score 1):

[This part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431pb243&name=Tile%201%20x%204%20with%20Wood%20Grain%20and%204%20Nails%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=88) is a typical wood plank with nails (which are metal) on it. There are many variations of it, and almost all of them have nails, therefore they don't really count. However I've looked at all variations and the only ones I can find that have more metal are [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431pb572#T=C&C=120), [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87079pb077) and [this one.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431pb573#T=C&C=120)